# Whatelse I try to import "Unable to resolve target 'android-8'" error appear

Tags: android, api, google-maps, importerror

Well I try to use google maps api v2. so that I need to import:

sdk/extras/google/google_play_service

if I import, there are some errors

```
[2014-02-13 22:32:55 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'
[2014-02-13 22:32:56 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'
[2014-02-13 22:34:51 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2014-02-13 22:34:52 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
```

I have uninstall everything and install again but problem is still accuer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to download the right Android API version from adt (here 8 & 9).

Comment: yeah yu are right. but after I recognize that this is not really importnt .it is just a warning.

Comment: Note that Android API 9 is considered obsolete, so you need to click on the obsolete checkbox to have it visible in the list for download.

Answer (score 1):

Are you use you have downloaded the correct verion of google play services.
There are two versions
 1. for API 13 or greater 
 2. for API less then 13

If yes then Right click on your project select Properties(Alt+Enter), goto Android(Project build Target)-> Check Android 4.4.2 or earlier version which you have, click on Apply-> OK, that's it.
finally clean your project.